# how to create a template class in C++ whose datatype is not known

Tags: c++, templates, types

I want to create an image template class. this class will read the image data from a file and store the data in its member variable.
The datatype of the image is stored in the image's header and is not known before hand.

how do I create a image template class without knowing the datatype of the image? the image read function will read the header and will allocate that memory depending upon the datatype of the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A template won't do much to automate this. A template lets you delay dealing with (some) specific details of a type until compile time instead of when the code is written--but when the code is compiled, all the details of the types and values used as template parameters must be be known. They specifically do *not* deal with variations in type that are unknown until run-time as you're dealing with here.

What you're discussing sounds like it fits a lot more closely with a classical OOP model, with a base "Image" class, and a derived class for each type of image (e.g., BmpImage, JpegImage, TiffImage, etc.) Then you'd have some sort of ImageFactory class that reads in the data, instantiates an object of some type derived from Image, and finally returns an `Image *` to that newly defined object, so that client code can display, manipulate, etc., the image as needed.

The obvious alternative (also quite widely used) is to read in the external data, convert from its external format into some uniform internal format, and create an object representing the image in that internal format. Just for example, on Windows you might read external files and convert them all to Windows bitmaps.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your alternative is to read the datatype of the image from the header outside the class and instantiate the object of the image class based on that datatype and call a read image function on the object to read the pixel values from the file based on the datatype passed to the object?

Comment: @RiteshBanka: The details vary (widely). For example, you might just read the initial signature externally, then based on that invoke a ctor or streaming operator of the individual class to construct itself from a stream.

Answer (score 1):

as far as you get type dynamically you can not use templates directly (templates implement static polymorphism)

if you know all types of images you can combine 2 approaches: declare an abstract class and instatiate your template class (derived from base) with these types and use a sort of factory to create corresponding class.

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual int getWidth() = 0;
};

template <class T> class ImageOfSomeType : public base
{
public:
   virtual int getWidth() { return width; };
};
// in a cpp file:
//The explicit instantiation part
template class ImageOfSomeType <MyType1>; 
template class ImageOfSomeType <MyType2>;
```

and in some place ()

```
base * createImage()
{
   ...
   if (image_type == "type1") return new ImageOfSomeType<MyType1>;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Will it be a good design if I read the header of the image file outside the class, get the type of the image from the header and pass based on the type create a template class and read the pixel values from the file based on the type?

Comment: actually you have to do so anyway. In order to make a decision what class to create you need the type of image. So you wiil have a simple image header parser to read the type of image.